# Putting a theorem before a two column article starts

Tags: formatting, theorems, article

I am writing an article about a theorem and I want my article to have two columns. I'm using

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twocolumn]{article}
```

I want to write the statement of the theorem

```
\begin{theorem}
statement
\end{theorem}
```

before the two column document starts. More precisely, the statement of the theorem should be in one column and then the rest of the article should start from the next line in two-column style.

Maybe there is a way to include it in the title? Can someone help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: Simply use the `strip` environment from the `cuted` package (`sttools` bundle).

Comment: @Bernard That works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Bernard Would you like to add an answer, just to leave out this question from the unanswered list?

Comment: @CarLaTeX! 'Tis done, milady! Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: @Bernard You're welcome! Upvoted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a follow-up, here is an example code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage[standard]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{strip}
\begin{theorem}[Faustroll]
God is the shortest path from $0$ to $\infty$.
\end{theorem}
\end{strip}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]